# Remote call using bootstrap validator

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I would like to check whether the email id already exist or not while in registration page. For this I am using remote validator. My code is here. User can add more employees while registration. That's why I used emp_email[]. If email is not there in database, I am returning as 0, and if the same email id exist in DB, I am returning 1. But I am confused how to validate that 0 and 1 in the below bootstrap validator code? Any help would be appreciated.

```
'emp_email[]': {
    validators: {
        notEmpty: {
            message: 'Email Field required and cannot be empty'
        },
        emailAddress:{
            message: 'The value is not a valid email address'
        },
        remote: {
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/ti/public/isEmployeeEmailExist',
            //Send { username: 'its value', email: 'its value' }
            data: function(validator) {
                return {
                 'emp_email': validator.getFieldElements('emp_email').val()
                };
            },
            message: 'The employee email is available'
        }
     }
 },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this problem . The return value from the remote call must be in the form of json format. and it need to return either true or false.
so i did if email already exist i am sending false and if email is not there in db i am sending true. So based on the true / false if the return value is false the error message what we mention will display.

```
if($cnt == 0)
    {
        $isAvailable = true;
    }else{
        $isAvailable = False;
    }   
        // Finally, return a JSON
        echo json_encode(array(
        'valid' => $isAvailable,
        ));
```

Comment: how to do it with jsp and servlet ? if possible explain